# unable to deploy camel-web in Karaf 2.1.0

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm unable to deploy camel-web in Karaf 2.1.0...here is what i tried from a clean install of Karaf...

features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.6-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
features:install war
features:install camel
osgi:install -s mvn:org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE
osgi:install -s mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-web/1.2.0
war:mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-web/2.6-SNAPSHOT/war?Webapp-Context=camelweb

At this point, it seems like it deployed successfully as I don't see any errors in the logs.  But, when I go to http://localhost:8181/camelweb, I get a 404.

What am I missing?

Also, referenced with this JIRA ticket ([CAMEL-3519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3519))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug with this deployment process that is being worked by the Apache guys...see details [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3519)

Answer (score 0):

In a future Camel release there will be a feature to install camel-web. Its a bit tricky to dot that in the realms of OSGi :)

I suggest you get engaged in the Camel community and help with CAMEL-3519.
The best place is the Camel mailing list where all the good people is listening.

Comment: And as always try with Karaf 2.1.3 and Camel 2.6 when its out

Comment: thanks Claus, I am working on this JIRA issue and added these comments there as well.  I thought I'd throw it out to this community as well...